# Spark ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS explanation

Tags: apache-spark

Can someone explain with a practical example how ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS is effected?

Reading on this topic is not really clear.

I looked here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/EnsureRequirements.scala but not sure what to make of it. Some sort of insurance by Spark that things go well? I find the documentation cryptic.

You can refer to another SO question of mine: [Spark JOIN on 2 DF's with same Partitioner in 2.4.5 vs 3.1.2 appears to differ in approach, unfavourably for newer version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906968/spark-join-on-2-dfs-with-same-partitioner-in-2-4-5-vs-3-1-2-appears-to-differ-i). There I experimented but do not get the gist of why this is occuring.

None of my colleagies can explain it either.

Comment: Hey, could you clarify whats the concern here? As far as I know, `ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS` simply marks a shuffle as internal and thus "optimizable" by AQE, as opposed to `REPARTITION_BY_xxx`. [Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/ShuffleExchangeExec.scala#L87).

Comment: I cannot understand their explanation. Period. Can you give an example and answer the question. Thx for the link but an example would be nice. @mazaneicha none of our data engineers know of it. AQE context only?

Comment: "Simple" QE too I think, not necessarily **A**QE, sorry... I'll try to come up with a comprehensible answer, in the meantime there is always a bounty option to attract real experts. BTW, why would your data engineers need to know about QE internals tho? ;)

Comment: @mazaneicha we have a keen community and i am also keen. Awaiting answer from maine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume we want to find out how weather affects tourist visits to Acadia National Park:

```scala
scala> spark.sql("SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10")
scala> val ds = spark.sql("SELECT Date, AVG(VisitDuration) AvgVisitDuration FROM visits GROUP BY Date")
scala> ds.createOrReplaceTempView("visit_stats")
scala> val dwv = spark.sql("SELECT /*+ MERGEJOIN(v) */  w.*, v.AvgVisitDuration FROM weather w JOIN visit_stats v ON w.Date = v.Date")
scala> dwv.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [Date#91, MaxTemp#92, AverageTemp#93, MinTemp#94, Precip#95, Conditions#96, AvgVisitDuration#216]
   +- SortMergeJoin [Date#91], [Date#27], Inner
      :- Sort [Date#91 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Date#91, 10), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#478]
      :     +- Filter isnotnull(Date#91)
      :        +- FileScan ...
      +- Sort [Date#27 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- HashAggregate(keys=[Date#27], functions=[avg(cast(VisitDuration#31 as double))])
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Date#27, 10), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#474]
               +- HashAggregate(keys=[Date#27], functions=[partial_avg(cast(VisitDuration#31 as double))])
                  +- Filter isnotnull(Date#27)
                     +- FileScan ...
```

Worth noting that a) Spark decided to shuffle both datasets using 10 partitions to calculate the average and to perform a join, both, and that b) shuffle origin in both cases is `ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS`.

Now lets say *visits* dataset is quite large, so we want to increase parallelism of our stats calculations and we repartitioned it to a higher number.

```scala
scala> val dvr = dv.repartition(100,col("Date"))
scala> dvr.createOrReplaceTempView("visits_rep")
scala> val ds = spark.sql("SELECT Date, AVG(AvgDuration) AvgVisitDuration FROM visits_rep GROUP BY Date")
scala> ds.createOrReplaceTempView("visit_stats")
scala> val dwv = spark.sql("SELECT /*+ MERGEJOIN(v) */  w.*, v.AvgVisitDuration from weather w join visit_stats v on w.Date = v.Date")
scala> dwv.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [Date#91, MaxTemp#92, AverageTemp#93, MinTemp#94, Precip#95, Conditions#96, AvgVisitDuration#231]
   +- SortMergeJoin [Date#91], [Date#27], Inner
      :- Sort [Date#91 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Date#91, 100), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#531]
      :     +- Filter isnotnull(Date#91)
      :        +- FileScan ...
      +- Sort [Date#27 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- HashAggregate(keys=[Date#27], functions=[avg(cast(VisitDuration#31 as double))])
            +- HashAggregate(keys=[Date#27], functions=[partial_avg(cast(VisitDuration#31 as double))])
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Date#27, 100), REPARTITION_BY_NUM, [id=#524]
                  +- Filter isnotnull(Date#27)
                     +- FileScan ...
```

Here, `REPARTITION_BY_NUM` shuffle origin dictated the need to have 100 partitions, so Spark optimized the other, `ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS`, origin to also use a hundred. Thus eliminating the need for another shuffle.

This is just one simple case, but I'm sure there are many other optimizations Spark can apply to DAG that contain shuffles with `ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS` origin.

Comment: That example I refer to not 100% explained but thx.